# Require other method to be called at top of function

Tags: scala, super

I was looking for a way to verify that a certain method is called before the rest of the function.

For example, if there is a `setup` function in a superclass `Super`, I want to ensure that every subclass calls `super.setup()` before the subclass does anything else, to make sure that everything is already set up before other methods are used.

The best I could get is this, which is not very easy or idiomatic

```
class CalledSuper

class Super {
  def setup() = {
    println("Doing some necessary things")
    new CalledSuper
  }

  def printText(s: String)(implicit ev: CalledSuper) = println(s)
}

class Foo extends Super {
  override def setup() = {
    //printText("In subclass's method") error: Could not find implicit value
    implicit val proof = super.setup()
    printText("In subclass's method")
    proof
  }

  def fooBar() = {
    printText("I don't need to call super.setup")(new CalledSuper)
  }
}
```

This isn't very nice, though

1. It forces me to assign the result of `setup` to an `implicit val`.
2. It forces my overridden `setup` method to return a `CalledSuper` object.
3. It forces me to make all the methods in the `Super` class accept a `CalledSuper` object.
4. It only works with methods that are inside the `Super` class. The subclass's `setup` function can still use other methods before calling `setup`. However, this is not too much of a concern.

My main problem is with #3. It's inconvenient because if I have some other method `fooBar` that also needs to use the `printText` method (which  currently takes an implicit parameter) but doesn't need to call `super.fooBar`, then it's just annoying, because I have to needlessly create a `CalledSuper` object even when not necessary.

I was wondering if there was a better way to require a method to be called before some other methods (not just for calling `super.foo` but to require any method to be called), since I couldn't find any questions about this for Scala. I'm fine with "hacks" and sketchy workarounds as long as they don't involve building entire compiler plugins (or anything else at that scale).

EDIT: To clarify, the example with `super.setup()` was only an example. There may be some other method, like `baz`, that doesn't have to call `super.baz()` but needs to call `validate()` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to design your overriding strategy a bit differently:

```
class Super {
  def superSetup() = {
    println("Doing some necessary things")
  }

  final def setup() = {
    superSetup()
    setupCustomize()
  }

  def setupCustomize() = {
  }

}


class Foo extends Super {
  override def setupCustomize() = {
    printText("In subclass's method")
  }
}
```

If you do not want the order of the `superSetup` be changeable, make it part of the implementation which is `final`.

Comment: Thanks! I saw a similar answer in a Java question, but didn't think I could apply it here because I also wanted to use it with other functions. I can probably adapt this to work with functions that aren't calls to `super.foo` too, I guess. I'm going to wait a few minutes to accept your answer though, just in case

Comment: it would be my recommendation as well, do something more like the template pattern :)

Comment: everyone needs rubber ducking some times :) don't worry